# Describe all points $Q$ such that the line through Q with direction vector $\vec v$ intersects the line $\vec x = \vec p + s \vec u$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec p=\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}, \vec u=\pmatrix{1\\1\\-1}, \vec v=\pmatrix{2\\1\\0}.$

Describe all points $Q=(a,b,c)$ such that the line through $Q$ with direction vector $\vec v$ intersects the line $\vec x = \vec p + s \vec u$

My approach:

I think that the points $Q$ lie on a plane which intersects with the line $\vec x$ and that one of the direction vectors of that plane is $\vec v$. However I am not sure what to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\overrightarrow{q}=(a,b,c)$ for the coordinates of point $Q$.

Then we have that $\overrightarrow{q}-\overrightarrow{p}$ must be in the plane spanned by the vectors $\overrightarrow{u},\overrightarrow{v}$. So the component of $\overrightarrow{q}-\overrightarrow{p}$ normal to the plane needs to be zero. Hence,

$$(\overrightarrow{q}-\overrightarrow{p})\cdot(\overrightarrow{u}\times\overrightarrow{v})=0 \tag{1}$$

The relevant vectors are

$$\overrightarrow{q}-\overrightarrow{p}=\begin{pmatrix}a-1\\b-2\\c-3\end{pmatrix}$$ 
and
$$\overrightarrow{u}\times\overrightarrow{v}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$
So the equation obeyed by point $Q$ is

$$(a-1)-2(b-2)-(c-3)=0 \tag{2}$$

As you correctly said, this is the equation of a plane.